# ActiveRecord Rails: Get records where a field is unique/distinct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, unique

I have a project Ruby 2.4.0 and Rails 5.0.1 and a model with the following:

```
class Hospital < ApplicationRecord

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :state
  validates_presence_of :unit
  validates_presence_of :site

  def self.get_hospitals
    hospitals = order(:name).all 
    grouped = hospitals.group_by(&:state)
  end  
end
```

I then use that "grouped" hash to populate a drop down box in which I display `h.name + ' (' + h.unit.to_s + ')'`.

My issue is that there can be duplicates in that list and if there is then I only want one of them.

How do I query the records and get returned the whole records (not pluck or select where only a single field is returned) whereby name is unique?

Something like:

```
hospitals = order(:name).distinct
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you can do it with SQL but it's possible with the [method `uniq` of Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
def self.get_hospitals
  hospitals = order(:name).all
  unique = hospitals.uniq(&:name)
  grouped = unique.group_by(&:state)
end
```

Comment: Hi João, For some reason this didn't have an effect for me and 'hospitals' and 'unique' were the same. But it did give me the idea to use uniq further down the path on the array that is passed to my drop down list (see my answer below), so thank you very much for the inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get all objects by a unique attribute:

```
Hospital.select('distinct on (name) *')
```

Comment: that just gives me an invalid MySQL error `Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on(name) * FROM `hospitals`' at line 1: SELECT distinct on(name) * FROM `hospitals``

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you

```
hospitals = order(:name).group(:name)
```

Comment: This causes issues for my 'grouped = hospitals.group_by(&:state)' line that follows. The error given is -- `Mysql2::Error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dev.hospitals.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by: SELECT `hospitals`.* FROM `hospitals` GROUP BY `hospitals`.`name` ORDER BY `hospitals`.`name` ASC`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [distinct](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct)

```
distinct.order(name: :desc)
```

If you want group by then you can also try [group](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group)

```
 distinct.group(:id, :state).order(name: :desc)
```

will give you instead of `hospitals.group_by(&:state)`

The query will return something like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT "hospitals".* FROM "hospitals" GROUP BY "hospitals"."id", "hospitals"."state"  ORDER BY "hospitals"."name" DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not giving me what I need. The first produces the following SQL `SELECT DISTINCT `hospitals`.* FROM `hospitals` ORDER BY `hospitals`.`name` ASC` and the second produces `SELECT DISTINCT `hospitals`.* FROM `hospitals` GROUP BY `hospitals`.`id`, `hospitals`.`state` ORDER BY `hospitals`.`name` ASC`

But neither of these actually give me distinct hospitals based on 'name'.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it working at the SQL level so I implemented a '.uniq' solution on the Array that I pass to my drop down list.

```
def self.get_hospitals
    hospitals = order(:name).all
    grouped = hospitals.group_by(&:state)

    output = grouped.collect { |state, hospitals| [state, hospitals.collect { |h| [h.name, h.id] }] }

    output.each do |key, value|
      value.uniq!
    end
    output.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
  end
```